# Should there be some type of chit-chat site on StackExchange?

Tags: feature-request

How about making something like chitchat.stackexchange.com where people would not have to necessarily ask questions but be more like a regular forum format to discuss things.

There could still be up/down votes but does not have to be a "best answers" feature.

Right now it's hard to start off-topic discussion as it is quickly killed by moderators and worst off you get a few down votes for something like that and lose reputation points.

I think many people sometimes want to just hang out and talk to other members of this site, maybe to share ideas or say something, but not necessarily in a form of a question.

I know there is a chat, but chat is something real-time. In chat you limited to talking to people who are already there in that chatroom with you at the same time. What if a want to post a topic and then check responses the next day and the next day....

Comment: If there is one thing I can say with complete confidence, it's that our chat is very much *not* limited to talking only to people who are present in the room with you. ♪

Comment: Very good. Sorry, I did not know that. I thought it was a traditional real-time chat.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Chat]

Chat rooms have full transcripts saved that you can access once you enter the room.

[image]

You also get a notification in your global SE inbox if someone @messages you in chat, so you can come right back to a conversation later if it continues on without you.

Comment: To be fair, they *did* put it right where a lot of us are used to ignoring ads...

Comment: It's also in the top bar, next to the link to either the main Q&A or the Meta.

Comment: You don't even have to enter the room to get the transcript. Just go to the main chat site (http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com, http://chat.stackoverflow.com, or http://chat.stackexchange.com), find the room, and click on the little gray number in the lower right corner of it.

Comment: Chat? You mean that is an actual _chat_? I thought it was w00t getting clever again!

Comment: For the record, @Grace comment is no longer true, the chat link has moved over the years

Answer (score 5):

I know you said Chat is not what you are looking for.  But it sounds like you haven't used it much, because what you describe is Chat.

Chat is real-time but logging out does not remove your messages.  You can come back and check for responses at a later time. You are not limited to just questions and answers and can talk about general items with other users.